# How to set exclamation point badge on app as in message app. i.e. '!'?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

How to set exclamation mark on app as its a character rather integer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that. The badge is an integer.

Comment: But how other apps are doing? Is there any field other than badgeNumber for that?

Comment: Which applications? It's not possible.

Comment: Messages application or other SMS applications have this to indicate failure of messages.

Comment: System-integrated applications have better possibilites, of course. Some applications (e.g. Twitter) have their own pages in System Settings but normal applications can't do that. You can never do the same as system applications.